# If a new Frame show up setEditable(false) , If the user close it setEditable(true)

Tags: java, swing, exception, jframe, jtextfield

I want to create this code :
The user enter a numerical value , if he entered character it will throw exception 
the field will stop working then another frame show up and display error message 
after the user close the new frame , everything return to the way it is 
that means the field will work again !
I managed to make the field stop working but I didn't know if the user closed the new frame or not !
here is my try

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {

try{
double l,h,w;
l=Double.parseDouble(input_length.getText());
w=Double.parseDouble("0"+input_width.getText());
h=Double.parseDouble("0"+input_width.getText());
}

catch(NumberFormatException a){


input_length.setEditable(false);
input_height.setEditable(false);
input_width.setEditable(false);

JFrame ErrorFrame = new JFrame("Error");
JPanel content = new JPanel(); ;
ErrorFrame.setContentPane(content);

ErrorFrame.setSize      (350, 150);
ErrorFrame.setResizable (false);
ErrorFrame.setLocation  (FRAME_X_ORIGIN, 250);

content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
JLabel text = new JLabel(" ERROR ! please Enter number only ",JLabel.CENTER);
text.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
text.setForeground(Color.red);
content.add(text);
ErrorFrame.setVisible(true);

setDefaultCloseOperation(ErrorFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
int op = ErrorFrame.getDefaultCloseOperation();

if(op == 1 ){
input_length.setEditable(true);
input_height.setEditable(true);
input_width.setEditable(true);}

}
}
```

Comment: Are you set on using a `JFrame` as your error message? I think a `JDialog` would work better. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: I have to use JFrame , that what they want

Answer (score 2):

1). Do not use new `JFrame` for error message - use `JDialog` [Here is how](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

2). `h=Double.parseDouble("0"+input_width.getText());` i think that you meant `input_height.getText()` here, not `input_width.getText()`

3). After showing your error dialog just clear your text fields - it is ok. When user will close it - he will see them empty.

Comment: Well , Our lesson was about JFrame so they don't want to user other than JFrame ! + if I cleared the text field it will return normal ?

Comment: + Thank you ! Ididn't notice the mistake here

Answer (score 1):

1. If you would opt for a modal dialog to show the error message, there is no need to change the editable state of your fields.
2. Personally as a user I would become quite irritated if a dialog was shown each time I made a typo. For example changing the background color of the text field to red on invalid input, and disabling the OK button (or whatever mechanism you have as user to indicate you are finished editing) is more user-friendly IMO. You can even show a label indicating the errors in your panel, or a tooltip, ... .
3. I would also recommend a `DocumentListener` instead of a `KeyListener` if you want to react on updates of the text in the text field

An example on why I propose to opt for another mechanism to inform the user of the error:
I paste an invalid value in the textfield (e.g. `3x456`) and a dialog pops up. Now I want to use my arrow keys to navigate to the error and correct it. This means I have to navigate 3 positions to the left to delete the `x`. If I use my arrow keys (which are keys as well) I will see this dialog 3 more times during the navigation.

Comment: Well , I'm still begginer 
I didn't learn about DocumentListener yet 
I Really thank you for the great info 
but all I took was JFrame , ActionListner and Keylistner
And I was asked to do this only by JFrame and setEditable